# Why is an added web form different from the default forms?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, webforms, visual-studio-2013

An ASP.NET Webforms project has some default pages ("About" and "Contact" to be specific), which have this type of content:

```
<%@ Page Title="About" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="About.aspx.cs" Inherits="About" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <h2><%: Title %>.</h2>
    <h3>Your application description page.</h3>
    <p>Use this area to provide additional information.</p>
</asp:Content>
```

Yet when you select Add > Web Form, it creates this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="DuckbilledPlatypus.aspx.cs" Inherits="DuckbilledPlatypus" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Why the difference/inconsistency? Note: This is in Visual Studio 2013; I'm not positive other versions are the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't create the Web Form using the Master Page. When you right click the project, click Add Item, then under Web it will have Web Form and then other classes as well. Using the Web Form using Master Page should give you the one that you want. The one that it sounds like you used is the blank web form and has no site.master linked up to it where the Web Form using Master Page links up the site.master for you.